# Apply a function to each element of an unspecified number of vectors

Tags: dictionary, clojure

Say I have two vectors:

```clj
(def x [1 2 3])
(def y [4 5 6])
```

and I want to apply a function (e.g., `+`) to each element in these vectors sequentially, like so:

```clj
(defn mapply
  [x y]
  (map + x y))
```

This function works just fine, producing `(5 7 9)`. Now, I want to be more generic and apply the function over potentially any number of vectors. My initial thought is that I need the `&` parameter.

```clj
(defn mapply
  [& vecs]
  (map + vecs))
```

Clearly, this doesn't work and throws the error:

> Cannot cast clojure.lang.PersistentVector to java.lang.Number

Presumably, I need to unpack `vecs` into individual vectors, but I don't know how many there will be so I'm not sure how to destructure `vecs` appropriately. My mind goes to `apply` next to explode `vecs` into separate vectors, perhaps something like this:

```clj
(defn mapply
  [& vecs]
  (apply (fn [& stuff] (map + stuff)) vecs))
```

but I think this is essentially more code doing exactly the same thing.

How would I go about making this function accept any number of vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
(defn mapply [& vecs]
  (apply map + vecs))

(mapply [1 2 3] [10 40 60] [1000 10000 1000000])
;; => (1011 10042 1000063)
```

See the [documentation for `apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply). We use the form `(apply f x args)` where `f` is `map` and `x` is `+`.

Comment: Amazing - thanks! It seems I was on the right track with `apply`, but I totally botched how to actually use it.

Comment: You're welcome! I suppose that we often only learn the form `(apply f args)` and forget about the higher arity ones.

Answer (score 1):

@Rulle's answer is correct.

Your name `mapply` makes one expect a very generic `map`-and-`apply` where one can pass the function explicitly - but you assume it always to be `+`.

Maybe you should give the possibility to enter the function-for-the-`map` explicitly.

And call your function `map-+`:

```
(defn mapply [fun & vecs]
  (apply map fun vecs))

(defn mapply-+ [& vecs]
  (apply mapply + vecs))

(mapply-+ [1 2 3] [10 40 60] [1000 10000 1000000])
;; => (1011 10042 1000063)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gwang-Jin – that was the next step! First, I wanted to get it working with a hardcoded function. Next, I was expanding to use any function.